# Display the Pixels of Bayer Format Image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have just started using OpenCv-Python. 
I want to see the pixel values of an image which is in Bayer format. Using OpenCv-Python, I have written the following code to display the pixel values :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("bayer_small.png")
image_data = np.array(image)
print(image_data[50][50])

#Output is printed as " [ 0 0 102]
```

My expectation is single pixel value : 102

Why is this happening? Since the image is only in Bayer format, I am expecting one component only per pixel.

I understand that output is showing zero for other two components. But I am expecting the data in the bayer format only, for example : BGBGBGBG for first line.

My goal is to implement an algorithm. Hence trying to do step by step.

Edit 1: Is there any in-built function where I can convert a normal image to Bayer format?

Comment: Do `cv2.imread("bayer_small.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`.

Answer (score 3):

While your picure probably contains the data from the Bayer matrix, it obiously still uses the RGB format for containing it. You can probably assume that two channels contain 0 for each pixel; thus you should apply a vectorized sum to the whole picture along the third axis with:

```
data = np.sum(image_data, axis=2)
```

in order to normalize it.

By the way, you can access data in a Numpy array with the more concise syntax: `data[50, 50]` instead of `data[50][50]`.

Comment: Just to complete your answer, `cv2.imread("bayer_small.png")` by default loads a BGR image, with `cv2.imread("bayer_small.png", flag)` it can be override. `IMREAD_GREYSCALE` or `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` are the possible best flags to use in this case.